# Wrapped component still renders when redux state says it shouldn't

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this `Protected` HOC. Its purpose is to only render its `WrappedComponent` when the user is authenticated. Otherwise the `AuthenticateComponent` should be rendered (usually a login component).

```
import React from "react"

const PROPTYPES = {
  authenticated: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
}
export default (WrappedComponent, AuthenticateComponent) => {
  let Protected = (props) => (
    props.authenticated
    ? <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
    : <AuthenticateComponent {...props}/>
  )
  Protected.propTypes = PROPTYPES
  return Protected
}
```

The props for the component come from a connected redux Container component

```
const AccountContainer = ({ children }) => (
  <div>{children}</div>
)
const select = state => state.account
export default connect(select, { refreshUser, logout })(Protected(AccountContainer, LoginContainer))
```

my `account` reducer looks like this:

```
function authenticated(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.START_SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
    case actions.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return true
    case actions.LOGIN_ERROR:
    case actions.START_SIGNUP_ERROR:
    case actions.LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return false
    default:
      return state
  }
}

...

export default combineReducers({
  authenticated,
  access_token,
  loggingIn,
  user,
  error,
})
```

It happens now that when the `LOGOUT` action is set the `state.account.authenticated` property is set to false, and yet, the `WrappedComponent` is still rendered. It accesses various other properties of `account` and they all have been cleared also already, which the component does not check and expect. The `WrappedComponent` assumes that when it gets rendered the `account` state is still `authenticated` and therefor valid.

I wonder what kind of race condition might that be?

Answer (score 1):

I can't know without seeing the code but it looks like your reducer mutates the state. A reducer should never mutate the state.  It should instead make a new state with the right properties.

The whole point of that is to prevent race conditions and other anomalies.

React Redux has been very carefully designed to prevent the kinds of issues you're seeing here. It does require that you bide by the Redux rules. The main one is that reducers *must* be pure functions.

If your reducer modifies the old state and returns that instead, Redux has no easy way to see that you made modifications to the state.  In fact it will assume no changes were made. As such nothing will be rerendered.

**Edit:**

Your reducer looks fine, even though I can't see how the `account` reducer is used elsewhere, I assume it's fine as well.

What I believe to be the issue is that your component does, in fact, not get rendered, but the render method still gets called on `LOGOUT`. What's happening is that React will happily render a subcomponent if that subcomponent asks for such a render. And since `connect` hooks into the `store` updates to make that happen, this is what's going on.

When your state changes, `connect` will re-evaluate the `props` of `WrappedComponent` by calling `mapStateToProps` and it will find that those props have changed (due to no longer being logged in, and this data therefore being different than it was before). Connect will then instruct React to re-render the `WrappedComponent`. React will do that. Your `render` method, then, in turn, probably has trouble with the data it is being passed because it's invalid data meant only to be used when a user is logged in.

The solution is to simply exit the render with a dummy `<div/>`. This div, a virtual DOM element, will actually never make it into the DOM. React caches elements and batches DOM updates. React will therefore prune the whole `WrappedComponent` before it merges it into the DOM, and, unfortunately, after it has already rendered the new version.

Note that it's Redux in combination with Connect that really are the culprit here, because Redux has no notion of Components and can therefore not take them into account, whereas Connect subscribes to the store in the order it is created in, and the store then notifies the components in the order they were subscribed.

The final order depends on render order and mounting order and many components play a role in deciding this order. It's simply not stable and should therefore not be counted on.

When you build a connected component, make sure to write your `mapStateToProps` to take *any* valid state and compile *valid* props from those for the target component. Whether you add dummy values, or change the component itself to make anything you pass to it valid, it's important to allow all valid states, to resolve to valid props, even if the component these props are for are never meant to be displayed. This way, you prevent errors due to invalid props that in fact result from a valid state (being logged out is a valid state to be in).

Of course it is not not necessary to deal with invalid state as it should never occur, not even for an instant.

Comment: I have edited my question with my reducer code. Looks ok to you?